# $_POST in ajax page showing error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using an ajax request to change password 
this is my code

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'change-password.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data : $("#frm-change-password").serialize(),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#btn-change-pasword").attr('disabled','disabled')
                $("#change-password-msg").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" width="30"><span>Updating Password</span>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#change-password-msg").html(data);
                $("#btn-change-pasword").removeAttr('disabled');
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.success').remove(); }, 7000);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
```

my problem is I am not able to get the form data in 'change-password.php' page

I'm getting like this "Notice: Undefined index: bsns-id in..."

is I use GET Instead of POST everythis is working perfectly.

Comment: kindly tell me the wrong I have done when u giving negative mark so that I can change in the future questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071535/jquery-validation-plugin-does-not-send-post-data 

Similar Question

Comment: How are you getting `POST`ed data in your `change-password.php`?

if you use type = POST then you MUST use `$_POST` ...

Answer (score 1):

Look at your PHP code. And see whether you are accessing the data via `$_GET[]` or `$_POST[]` array. If you use GET method to send the data(from AJAX), then all the values would be in the `$_GET[]` associative array. Or if you are using the POST method, then the data would be in `$_POST[]` array.

**EDIT**

I believe the data is not being sent to the server. Lets try to debug from the client side. Do you know how to use the Developer Tools of the Google Chrome? Open the page in Chrome browser and before you are going to initiate the ajax submission, open up the Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I). Then click on `Network` tab. Now initiate the AJAX submission. And then check the details of the data being sent. Check whether any data is being submitted and verify it.

You could also take a look at the `Console` window and see whether there is any errors being shown. If there's some errors, then that might be preventing the rest of the javascript from executing. So, keep an eye on the console window too.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Am running out of solutions now. Probably you need to show us some more code or provide any links to the live page(if you uploaded somewhere) so that we could inspect more. Anyway, my last suggestion is, are you making this ajax call inside the `submitHandler` function of the jquery validation that you are applying on that form? Because [as per the documentation of the jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-form-submit), you could do the manual form submission(ie. the ajax call in your case) inside it.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I am accessing through  $_POST[] only

Comment: if( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        require "connection.php";
        $businessId = $_POST['bsns-id'];
}

Comment: Okay. Then try to debug it by dumping the contents of  `$_POST` array and see if the `bsns-id` element is there. You can use `var_dump( $_POST );` which prints all the elements of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: var_dump returns 0 value but I got similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071535/jquery-validation-plugin-does-not-send-post-data

Comment: post your change-password.php code so that i can get the code working for you in a minute. just hurry

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh for your help.
it is sending data to the php page and I can see it in my network tab if I use GET instead of POST everything is working perfectly but in POST I thik it is not sending data I am using jquery Validate for form validation 

     submitHandler: function() {
    }

Comment: Okay. I edited the answer with my final suggestion. If that too didn't work, you should upload that page to some server and give us the link so that we could try testing it live.

Comment: Thanks again Akhilesh but I got the answer 
I just deleted
contentType: false,
processData: false,

now it is working good